# Selecting only the first item of an xpath result set in PHP

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I am currently achieving the desired outcome with two PHP statements:

```
$thisBlarg = $xmlResource->xpath('//blarg[@ID='.$someBlargID.']');
echo $thisBlarg[0]->name;
```

But, not wanting to settle for second best, I'd really prefer this to be one statement, but PHP doesn't like this:

```
echo $xmlResource->xpath('//blarg[@ID='.$someBlargID.']')[0]->name;
```

And for good reason. But I can't find a way to force an xpath query to return the result directly.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `name` an element that is child of `blarg` or is it something PHP-specific?

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer. My example assumes that $xmlResource was instantiated as such: $xmlResource = simplexml_load_file('someXMLfile.xml');  So, the 'name' property corresponds to one of the elements of the supposed XML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
echo current(($xmlResource->xpath('//blarg[@ID='.$someBlargID.']')))->name;
```