# SimpleXMLElement get first XPath Element in one line

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

Just trying to figure a shorter way to do this:

I'm using simpleXMLElement to parse an xml file and it's aggravating to have to call two lines to process an array when I know what node I want.

Current code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$r = $xml->xpath('///givexNumber');
$result["cardNum"] = $r[0];
```

What I would like to do would be something like I can do with DomX

```
$result["cardNum"] = $xml->xpath('///givexNumber')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: Related: [Selecting only the first item of an xpath result set in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778146/selecting-only-the-first-item-of-an-xpath-result-set-in-php) (about accessing the first element *directly*, not storing it into a variable like here)

Answer (score 2):

In PHP < 5.4 (which supports  array dereference the result of a function or method call) you can access the first element either with the help of [`list`](http://php.net/list):

```
list($result["cardNum"]) = $xml->xpath('//givexNumber');
```

Since PHP 5.4 it's more straight forward with:

```
$result["cardNum"] = $xml->xpath('//givexNumber')[0];
```

Take care that these only work without any notices if the xpath method returns an array with at least one element. If you're not sure about that and you need a default value this can be achieved by using the array union operator.

In PHP < 5.4 the code that has the default return value of `NULL` would be:

```
list($result["cardNum"]) = $xml->xpath('//givexNumber[1]') + array(NULL);
```

For PHP 5.4+ it's similar, here a benefit is the new array syntax just with square brackets:

```
list($result["cardNum"]) = $xml->xpath('//givexNumber[1]') + [NULL];
```

---

See as well:

- [PHP: Access Array Value on the Fly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13109/367456)

---

> *Note in the margin:* Because you only expect one element, you should not return more than one by the xpath already:
>
> ```
> $result["cardNum"] = $xml->xpath('//givexNumber[1]')[0];
>                                                ###
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know php too well, but shouldn't:

```
$result["cardNum"] = (new SimpleXMLElement($data))->xpath('///givexNumber')[0]
```

be the same as

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$r = $xml->xpath('///givexNumber');
$result["cardNum"] = $r[0];
```

> *Edit Jul 2013:* Yes it does since PHP 5.4. With the little correction I added. That means all stable (non-end-of-life) versions of PHP as of now support that.

Comment: One would think.  But $r = $xml->xpath('///givexNumber')[0] does not work.