# PHP: xPath - write first element in variable in 1 line

Tags: php, arrays, xpath

This is what I have:

```
$namex = $xml->xpath("//a[@b=foo]/c");
$name = $namex[0];

echo $name;
```

It works, as the first line creates an array and the second line reads the first entry. Is there a way to combine the two lines to get the intended result right away?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php simplexmlelement get first element in one line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815639/php-simplexmlelement-get-first-element-in-one-line)

Comment: Recommended reading: [PHP syntax for dereferencing function result](http://stackoverflow.com/q/742764/367456)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list`:

```
list($name) = $xml->xpath("//a[@b=foo]/c");
```

Comment: Good use of `list()`, but they'd still have to `echo`. So not a true one-liner.

Comment: Sorry @JasonMcCreary for not making my self clear, the 'echo' line was for testing. This is what I'm looking for!

Comment: @user1952748, no worries. In that case, +.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to combine the two lines to get the intended result right away?

Yes and no...

**PHP 5.4+:**

```
echo $xml->xpath("//a[@b=foo]/c")[0]; // array dereferencing, yay!
```

**PHP < 5.4:**

```
$names = $xml->xpath("//a[@b=foo]/c");
echo $names[0];
```

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, this is running in PHP 5.3 :D

Comment: No worries. You wouldn't want to use array dereferencing if you wanted other values as you'd have to rerun the method.