# PHP - Access first index of array of SimpleXML::xpath function

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I am using SimpleXML to get an element of an XML object specified by tag name and attribute... as follows:

```
$result = $xml->xpath('Stat[@Type="Venue"]');
$venue  = $result[0];
```

This works fine.

**However...** the following shortening gives me an error

```
$venue = $xml->xpath('Stat[@Type="Venue"]')[0];

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/handler.php on line 10
```

I've got to be being stupid.... but I cannot seem to figure this out.

Comment: That syntax `foo()[]` is called _array dereferencing_, and is brand new to PHP 5.4. it won't work in earlier versions.

Comment: Recommended reading: [PHP syntax for dereferencing function result (Apr 2009)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/742764/367456) and [PHP: Access Array Value on the Fly (Apr 2008)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13109/367456)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use an array like that. You need to pass it to a variable like so

```
$venue = $xml->xpath('Stat[@Type="Venue"]');
echo $venue[0];
```

I think in PHP 5.4 you will have the ability to access array from objects, but don't quote me on that.

Edit: Sorry about that, I copied and pasted the code from the OP. `[0]` slipped from my radar!

Comment: think you meant to remove the [0] from the first line, but otherwise yes this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, there's a couple of ways to do this, besides [how Eli suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9687093/367456). The first and easiest for you to implement would be to use current(). I found this in a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778146/selecting-only-the-first-item-of-an-xpath-result-set-in-php), so I can't take credit for this one :)

```
$vanue = current(($xml->xpath('Stat[@Type="Venue"]')));
```

The second solution is to use an XPATH query. The only reason to use a query over xpath is if you need to evaluate an expression. Everything I can find says this should also work for you, but as I said, is not necessary and may not even work with your version of PHP. I know it doesn't with mine, so obviously I wasn't able to test it.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->Load($file);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = 'Stat[@Type="Venue"]';
$venue = $xpath->query($query)->item(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

### New features PHP 5.4.0

Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. foo()[0].

Use PHP 5.4.0 or higher.